# not able to find nunit.framework while using icsharplibrary

Tags: asp.net-3.5, unzip

I am trying to code for unzipping a file after uploading it on the sever and using following library to achieve this:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sharpdevelop/SharpZipLib_0855_SourceSamples.zip

But i am not able to add reference nunit.framework in my application. Where can i find this framework? I am not able to find it in the sample project that they have provided.

Thanks

Comment: you probably don't need nunit framework in order to read a zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find what you are looking for at

[NUnit Downloads](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download)